# Two IP-Adresses one NIC

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a server which needs two ip adresses. One internal ip address and one public ip address.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

This is my current configuration `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.115
    netmask 255.255.255.128
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.139
    netmask 255.0.0.0
    #gateway 10.0.0.1
```

The problem i experience is that i cant connect to the server via the internal ip address.
Everytime i try `ifup eth0:1` i get the following

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0:1
```

The only way to get the internal ip address working is to flush the interface before bringing up the virtual interface with `ip addr flush dev eth0 && ifup eth0:1` directly after the rebooting the server. But then i get the same error on the main interface.

I also i tried to rename the second interface to `eth0:0` and using the interface with the gateway. But i experienced the same errors.

Comment: The second stanza should say `eth0`, not `eth0:anything`. And of course if you are trying to put an IP address on the wrong network, it's not going to work anyway.

Comment: Are you sure the interface isn't already up?

Answer (score 1):

According to Debian's documentation, you do not necessarily need to use interface aliases (the :1) to set multiple addresses. 
However with or without using labels, the solution you've posted should be working as intended -- and I tested it without problems on a debian 7 box.

Since you've mentionned that you've been required to run an ip addr flush on the interface to get the other working, it's possible that your NIC's Driver simply does not allow several IPs for some reason... Maybe it doesn't properly separate MII/PHY/Interfaces ? Maybe it supports TCP/IP-offload but the implementation is such it only supports one address ? Maybe..

Please note however that it doeesn't make much sense to set a gateway on several interfaces, since the gateway sets a default route: you'd be sending all your traffic to two different places at the same time, and as such the interface with the lowest metric would be prefered.